# Access and modify the Textbox's ContextMenu Items

Tags: vb.net

I'm using vb.net 2013.

Is there any way to access and modify the TextBox's context menu items ?

I want to hide some of these items.

And I want to translate the caption.

Thank you !

Comment: You can create your own with whatever you want on it and replace it

Comment: I know that , but this is not my question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is.  Example below, where you hide based on a condition that you have set.

```
if (yourCondition) then  
yourTextBox.ContextMenuStrip.Items.RemoveByKey(theNameOfTheStrip)
end if
```

I'm not sure what you mean by the caption (but i think it is the text)

```
yourTextBox.ContextMenuStrip.Items.Item(theIndexOrKeyHere).Text
```

Comment: The caption is the text .But where I can test this code ? Should I use a specific event or ?????. And the nameofthestrip are the names that appear on the menu or is something else ?

Comment: You can test it on a sub which is probably an event handler for a click or selection. theNameOfTheStrip is the name of the ContextMenuStrip (if it is known to you), but if it is not, you can also use RemoveAt() where you will specify the index (which maybe much easier). Also, the "name" is most of the time different from the "text" of a contextmenustrip item.

Comment: Where can I find the name of ContextMenuStrip. The only thing I know is what I can see when the default original menu is showing. Can I use the menuitem's name or you mean something else ?

Comment: If the ContextMenuStrip was created at design time, the easiest way is to go to the designer, look at the bottom part where the contextmenustrip is located, then view the properties.

Comment: Sorry , I'm speaking for the default textbox's ContextMenu. and this is not created at design time , because is attached to control by operating system ( as I know). Textbox  has a default contextmenu , that is the same for example when you right click inside notepad.

Comment: Okay if it is the default contextmenu then as of know i think that you cannot edit the menuitems. What you can do is create a contextmenustrip(and its items) at runtime and assign it to your textbox.For that one you will really be in control :)